# AJAX loopback for getting a list of items - good idea?

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, recursion

I have a script `index.php` that dynamically via AJAX loads a list of items generated in `ajax.php`.

The list may not contain all desired items if there are too many. In such case, I want to give user a button *Show all items* that would load `ajax.php` again but request all the items.

I had an idea, that `ajax.php` would echo this button. When pressed, `ajax.php` would dynamically call itself but with a GET parameter for all items. Is it a good idea?

Thanks!

Here's simplified code:

**index.php**

```
<div id="ajax-out" />
<script> 
    $.get("ajax.php", function(out){
        $("#ajax-out").html(out);
    });
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
... list of items ...

<?php if the list isn't complete, print code below: ?>

    <a id="show-all">Show all items</a>

    <script>
        $("#show-all").click(function() {
            $.get("ajax.php?show_all", function(out){ // there's the loopback!
                $("#ajax-out").html(out);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I just have another idea. `ajax.php` would return XML cointaining HTML code of the list and a parameter if the list is complete. Then `index.php` could print *Show all items* button and call `ajax.php?show_all` itself. What do you think? Who should be the caller?

Comment: No. This is of course purely opinion, but I'd say it's much better to create the button in `index.php`. Any reason you're not doing that?

Answer (score 0):

> ajax.php would dynamically call itself but with a GET parameter for all items

if i'm reading this right, there would be multiple ajax calls just to get a list.

why not call the ajax one time and have it return the entire list? Multiple ajax calls when not necessary is highly inefficient, even if they are asynchronous and will not technically "block" the loading of the rest of the page.